# I need to re render state and make onChange operator work on input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to edit the input box in a table in a CRUD manner ,but I am unable to update the state and make the input box read-writable.
I am using redux-toolkit to dispatch action for fetching the employee list from json-server.

In the middleware redux-saga is used.
The link to git hub repo:https://github.com/grbknr1996/employee-manager

[image]
[image: The value is read only]

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import "./Home.scss";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { sagaActions } from "../redux/sagaActions";
    import { AiOutlineDelete, AiOutlineEdit } from "react-icons/ai";
    import { MdDone } from "react-icons/md";
    import { FormikBag, useFormik } from "formik";
    
    const Home: React.FC = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const employees = useSelector((state: any) => state.employees.employees);
      const [edit, setEdit] = useState({ edit: false, id: null as any });
      const [editInfo, setEditInfo] = useState(employees);
      const initialValues = {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        designation: "",
        address: "",
      };
    
      const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: initialValues,
    
        onSubmit: (values) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        },
      });
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({ type: sagaActions.FETCH_EMPLOYEES_SAGA });
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setInfo();
      }, [employees]);
    
      const setInfo = () => setEditInfo(employees);
      const handleEdit = (e: React.MouseEvent, index: number) => {
        console.log(index);
        setEdit({ edit: true, id: index });
      };
    
      const handleDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent, index: number) => {
        dispatch({ type: sagaActions.DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SAGA, id: index });
      };
      const toggleEdit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        console.log("edit toggle");
        setEdit({ edit: false, id: null as any });
      };
    
      const handleEditChange = (e: any, index: number) => {
        setEditInfo(
          employees.map((emp: any) =>
            emp.id === index ? (emp.name = e.target.value) : emp
          )
        );
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="main-container">
          <div className="table-container">
            <div className="table-row heading">
              <div className="row-item">ID</div>
              <div className="row-item">NAME</div>
              <div className="row-item">DESIGNATION</div>
              <div className="row-item">ADDRESS</div>
              <div className="row-item">ACTIONS</div>
            </div>
    
            {editInfo.map((emp: any, index: number) =>
              edit.edit && edit.id === index ? (
                <>
                  <form>
                    <div className="table-row">
                      <div className="row-item" key={emp.id}>
                        {emp.id}
                      </div>
                      <input
                        className="row-item"
                        name="name"
                        value={emp.name}
                        onChange={(e) => handleEditChange(e, index)}
                      />
                      <input className="row-item" value={emp.designation} />
                      <input className="row-item" value={emp.address} />
                      <div className="row-item">
                        <button type="submit">
                          <MdDone
                            className="changeColor done"
                            onClick={(e) => toggleEdit(e)}
                          />
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </>
              ) : (
                <div className="table-row">
                  <div className="row-item" key={emp.id}>
                    {emp.id}
                  </div>
                  <div className="row-item" key={emp.name}>
                    {emp.name}
                  </div>
                  <div className="row-item" key={emp.designation}>
                    {emp.designation}
                  </div>
                  <div className="row-item" key={emp.address}>
                    {emp.address}
                  </div>
    
                  <div className="row-item">
                    <AiOutlineEdit
                      className="changeColor edit"
                      onClick={(e) => handleEdit(e, index)}
                    />
                    <AiOutlineDelete
                      className="changeColor delete"
                      onClick={(e) => handleDelete(e, emp.id)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

export default Home;
```

Any will help will be great .Thanks in advance :) .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `value` for the input, use `defaultValue`

```html
<input className="row-item" name="name" defaultValue={emp.name} onChange={(e)=> handleEditChange(e, index)} />
```